# Samsung S5 wont connect to ubuntu 22.04 (usb)

Tags: usb, android, samsung

I am using an old phone, Samsung S5.  it cannot connect to ubuntu 22.04.  the phone will connect to windows 10 and after that works fine in ubuntu, until I do a power off.  then the problem starts again. seems to be a bug in ubuntu?  (using the wide usb cord, the regular cord doesnt work at all for usb communications but is fine for charging)

Comment: Watch `sudo journalctl  --follow` as you connect the phone. Read `man journalctl`.